# Table view very choppy on first scroll through

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am having problems with my tableview chopping excessively when I first scroll through. Once all of the cells have been displayed though, the scrolling turns very smooth. The table has 720 rows.

[Video of problem](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5322308/choppy2.mov)

My cell is set up like | image(32x32) - label - image(75x22) - image(75x22) | : [my cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9Txr.jpg)

I am testing this on an iPhone 6s. The images I have in the asset catalog are in the @2x slot and are sized 64x64 for the left image, and 150x44 for the right two images. Their file sizes are 5-9kb. I have not made any changes to the cell height. Using the default 44.

Heres my code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PokedexCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PokedexCell

    cell.thumb.image = UIImage(named: "\(dex[indexPath.row].name!)Thumb")
    cell.name.text = dex[indexPath.row].name
    if dex[indexPath.row].type2 == nil {
        cell.type1.image = nil
        cell.type2.image = UIImage(named: dex[indexPath.row].type1!)
    } else {
        cell.type1.image = UIImage(named: dex[indexPath.row].type1!)
        cell.type2.image = UIImage(named: dex[indexPath.row].type2!)
    }
    // check to make sure cells are being reused.
    if cell.tag != 999 {
        cell.tag = 999
        print("cell \(++self.cells)")
    }
    return cell
}
```

If I remove the line that sets the thumb image, the table works perfectly. I'm also not understanding the memory usage.

With thumb image: launch = 12.2mb, scrolled all the way to row 720 = 75.5mb (?!?!)

Without thumb image: launch = 10.3mb, scrolled all the way to row 720 = 12.1mb

So lets just say each thumb image is 10kb, if all were loaded were looking at a max of about 7mb.

Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:

Tried zp_x's suggestion by doing this:

```
var thumbs : [UIImage] = []
func getThumbs() {
    for x in 0...719 {
        thumbs.append(UIImage(named: "\(dex[x].name!)Thumb")!)
    }
}
```

Call getThumbs() in viewDidLoad. This entirely eliminates the choppiness BUT the app now takes ~7 seconds to load the page. Also once loaded memory usage starts at ~114mb, but scrolling all the way to the last row only increases usage to ~126mb. Also CPU usage when scrolling is much higher than before.

Does anyone have an idea what is happening with the thumb image? I'm not understanding how the memory usage could increase that much. The file sizes for the thumbs are from 5-9kb. so say even 10kb at max * 720 thumbs = 7200kb ~7mb. So confused...

Comment: not sure whether this will help, but you can have a try. Instead of loading image in your function every time, you can try to load all the images to an array or dictionary in viewDidLoad method and in this function, you read image from array or dictionary directly.

Answer (score 0):

try doing this in you cellForRowAtIndexPath
You should try to load the assets in the async block that helps to increase the performance to great extent.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) { () -> Void in
            //Start the process to read the image.

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                //set the image in here.
                cell.thumb.image = UIImage(named: "\(dex[indexPath.row].name!)Thumb")
                if dex[indexPath.row].type2 == nil {
                    cell.type1.image = nil
                    cell.type2.image = UIImage(named: dex[indexPath.row].type1!)
                } else {
                    cell.type1.image = UIImage(named: dex[indexPath.row].type1!)
                    cell.type2.image = UIImage(named: dex[indexPath.row].type2!)
                }

            })
        }
```

Comment: tried this with my original code, greatly improved performance but still a little choppy when scrolling very fast. what exactly is that code doing?

Comment: are you setting all the images inside this block ?

Comment: i've used it exactly as you have it. should i also move the other 2 images in here as well?

Comment: that works better, but it still chops a little on the first scroll through.

Comment: try to add the estimatedHeight for the tableviewcells using the 

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat

return the nearest estimated height for the cell.

Comment: try setting this too.. tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: that choppy effect is because the of dequeue of cell and change in the estimated. Once all your data has been loaded try to cache it and read from it instead loading it again and again

Answer (score 0):

You are loading all images synchonous. When loading images from the bundle's resources, iOS caches them (so: they will not get unloaded). That's why the second scroll through will be smooth.

You should either precache all images (by just calling UIImang(named:) for each image), or you fire UIImage(named:) in a separate thread and hand over the UIImage object to the image view on the main thread.

Comment: so lets say i wanted to precache all the images when the app is first launched, like when the loading screen is shown. how could i do that? I've never done any caching before, this is my first app

Comment: I don't recommend doing that. Your app could receive a memory warning and get killed by the OS. Also, this had a large impact on the battery. Just try the dispatch_async(...) as suggested above.